# TCPDF Maximum execution time. Where to increase that?

Tags: tcpdf

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in tcpdf.php on line 16304;

php.ini limits already updated,but cannot find where to increase TCPDF time limit.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution if the class or script implements `set_time_limit(0)` TCPD sets it's executing time limit as parameter given to set_time_limit.